# How to convert a loop to a Job-array in LSF cluster

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing, hpc, lsf, nextflow

I have 100 files, and I want to parallelise my submission to save time instead of running jobs one by one. How can I change this script to a Job-array in `LSF` using `bsub` submission system and run 10 jobs at every time?

```
#BSUB -J ExampleJob1         #Set the job name to "ExampleJob1"
#BSUB -L /bin/bash           #Uses the bash login shell to initialize the job's execution environment.
#BSUB -W 2:00                #Set the wall clock limit to 2hr
#BSUB -n 1                   #Request 1 core
#BSUB -R "span[ptile=1]"     #Request 1 core per node.
#BSUB -R "rusage[mem=5000]"  #Request 5000MB per process (CPU) for the job
#BSUB -M 5000                #Set the per process enforceable memory limit to 5000MB.
#BSUB -o Example1Out.%J      #Send stdout and stderr to "Example1Out.[jobID]"

path=./home/

for each in *.bam 
do 
samtools coverage ${each} -o ${each}_coverage.txt
done
```

Thank you for your time; any help is appreciated. I am a starter at `LSF` and am quite confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged your question with [nextflow](/questions/tagged/nextflow), so I will provide a minimal (untested) solution using Nextflow by enabling the [LSF](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/executor.html#lsf) executor. By using Nextflow, we can abstract away the underlying job submission system and focus on writing the pipeline however trivial. I think this approach is preferable, but it does place a dependency on Nextflow. I think it's a small one and maybe it's overkill for your current requirements, but Nextflow comes with other benefits, like being able to [modify and resume](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/getstarted.html#modify-and-resume) when those requirements inevitably change.

Contents of `main.nf`:

```
params.bam_files = './path/to/bam_files/*.bam'
params.publish_dir = './results'


process samtools_coverage {

    tag { bam.baseName }

    publishDir "${params.publish_dir}/samtools/coverage", mode: 'copy'

    cpus 1
    memory 5.GB
    time 2.h

    input:
    path bam

    output:
    path "${bam.baseName}_coverage.txt"

    """
    samtools coverage \\
        -o "${bam.baseName}_coverage.txt" \\
        "${bam}"
    """
}

workflow {

    bam_files = Channel.fromPath( params.bam_files )

    samtools_coverage( bam_files )
}
```

Contents of `nextflow.config`:

```
process {

    executor = 'lsf'
}
```

Run using:

```
nextflow run main.nf
```

Note also:

> LSF supports both *per-core* and *per-job* memory limit. Nextflow assumes
> that LSF works in the *per-core* memory limits mode, thus it divides the
> requested [memory](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-memory) by the number of requested [cpus](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-cpus).
>
> This is not required when LSF is configured to work in *per-job* memory
> limit mode. You will need to specified that adding the option
> `perJobMemLimit` in [Scope executor](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#config-executor) in the Nextflow configuration file.

Comment: This is so cool, Steve, and you gave also a wonderful explanation. I am gonna try it asap